# .NET type to store any possible number, or how to compare strings as numbers

Tags: .net, string, numbers, compare, double

We are developing an autofilter add-in for our .NET DataGrid control which works similar to the same MS Excel functionality. It allows entering custom filter criteria. We need to check whether a grid cell meets the custom filter condition, but the problem is that it is in the string format.
To optimize the performance, we could convert the string into the corresponding number and compare it to the cell value as real numbers, but what is the best .NET data type to store this cached value? Double is bad as we can lose some data (precision), BigInteger is good but only for integer values.
Another approach could be to compare the cell text and the string value to filter as numbers while they are in the string format. Can anybody know how to do that in .NET the best way? Or only in VB.NET as we're developing in this environment?

Comment: Why can't you simply compare...strings?

Comment: Just found this article: Numeric String Sort in C# [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11016/Numeric-String-Sort-in-C). Could be a basis for the development, but really want to compare numbers as real numbers as it is much faster.

Comment: A variable of type Object can store any data.

Comment: @Hans Passant, we need to go away from Object to avoid boxing/unboxing 100,000 times on huge grids.

Comment: You got one answer, that's doing boxing the hard and slow way.  Avoid writing your own spreadsheet component.

Comment: @Hans, we are really writing something like a spreadsheet component - the only difference is that it is a WindowsForms grid control called iGrid.NET (see http://www.10tec.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom class that is capable of storing all possible number formats:

```
class ParsedNumber {
 NumberType Type; //Integer, FloatingPoint, Decimal
 BigInteger Integer;
 double FolatingPoint;
 decimal Decimal;
}
```

This class should probably implement equality and comparison operators.

You can parse each cell into an instance of this class. The class should abstract the different formats so that you can just treat it as a number.

You could also make this a struct to save on heap allocations.

Comment: @Adriano, this is my second thought. I could implement our own string-as-number comparison algorithm, but aparently it will work very slow - taking into account the fact that we should parse every cell in a grid that canhave 100,000+ rows. I thought there could be ready-to-use solutions - inside .NET, or in other resources.

Comment: It seems, we really need to have 3-4 different number representations and use the best which correspond to the actual cell value type.

Comment: In my opinion you're right with that approach. You cannot fit all possible formats into one data type (at least not the built-in ones). But you can make one yourself.

Comment: We should have two different types for floating point values - float (Single in VB.NET) and double. As for "normal" integers, we need VB.NET's Long and ULong.

Comment: But maybe, even the best idea is to have about 10 possible corresponding representations just for any possible numeric data type? Then the comparison will be the fastest possible.

Comment: NumberType would be an enum denoting which of the number-holding fields is set. Only one should be set/valid at the same time.